# "org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path..." error with parametrized queries on JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a poblem on the first argument of the following method with the parametrized SQL query:

```
lista = miDao.find("SELECT c FROM Idioma WHERE c.palabra =:param", o1 , entityManager);
```

where:

```
String o1= "playa";
List<Object> lista;
```

The table "Idioma" has 3 columns "palabra", "idioma" and "wordId". The method is expected to look for the word "playa" within the column "palabra" and calls to the following Dao method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> find(String queryString, Object param, EntityManager em) {
    Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter( "param" , param);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

When I run the program I'm "rollbacked" with:

```
Unable to resolve path [c.palabra], unexpected token [c] [SELECT c FROM com.aprendeidiomas.entity.Idioma WHERE c.palabra =:param]
```

I'm sure I have a problem with my parametrized sql query. Even though I have red a lot of documents, I cannot solve my error. Could you pleas tell me what is wrong with my parametrized query?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is `c`? Do you mean `SELECT c FROM Idioma c ...`?

Comment: "c" is the parameter I want to replace for "playa"

Comment: No, the parameter would be `param`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, what you are using is not SQL but JPQL (or HQL as an extension).

Next, the error message already tells you what is wrong: `c` is unknown, hence `c.palabra` cannot be resolved. I assume you mean to select all idioms which match the word in `param` and your `Idioma` entity looks like this:

```
//Annotations and methods omitted for simplicity
class Idioma {
   String palabra; 
}
```

Thus your query should state that `c` is the alias for `Idioma`, i.e. 
  `SELECT c FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra =:param`.

A short break down:

- `SELECT c` - select whatever is meant by `c`
- `FROM Idioma c` - select Idioma entities and give them the alias `c` so that the query will know to return the entities that match
- `WHERE c.palabra = :param` - this condition means that all entities having the value passed as `param` (which is the value of `o1` in your example) match their `palabra` property.

As a clarification: after `query.setParameter( "param" , param);` the query *internally* might look like this:

```
SELECT c FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra = "playa"
```

Side note:
If you want to select the words instead, use `SELECT c.palabra ...`.

Comment: Comment for the Side note: you mean like "SELECT c.palabra FROM Idioma c =:param" ????

Comment: @VictorDoors no `SELECT c.palabra FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra =:param`

Comment: Just the last question related to this. What would be the command to retrieve all the "palabra" entries of my table considering that palabra is a column of my table Idioma? I am wondering that would be something like `SELECT c.palabra FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra = ""`

Comment: @VictorDoors first, with JPQL/HQL you should not think in terms of tables and columns but in terms of entities and properties. Second, you should think about what `WHERE c.palabra = ""` means: "return all entities where the property `palabra` is an empty string" -> clearly not what you want. Just try without a where clause to get _all_ entities: `SELECT c.palabra FROM Idioma c`.

Comment: Thank you again, you have been really helpful!. I much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `c`hould be an instace of `Idioma` ?
 So you have to add the alias to your statemen:

```
lista = miDao.find("SELECT c FROM Idioma c WHERE c.palabra =:param", o1 , entityManager);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but What you mean by add the alias? 
Note: "c" should be "playa" after the set parameter instance.

Comment: San you descripe what kind of object is c? Please add the entyties to your question!

Comment: You were right! I didn't understand what you meant with adding the alias until now. "c" is an instance of "Idioma".